# What algorithm does Python employ in bin(i) and int(x, base=2)?

Tags: python, int, bin

I'm using Python v3.6.3 to convert a integer to its binary representation (ex `bin(12)='0b1100'` and vice versa (ex `int('0b1100',2)=12`). I would like to know what algorithm is used. Can anybody clue me in?

Comment: If you're looking for the decimal->binary and binary->decimal conversion logic, that all happens when the bytecode compiler parses the `12` literal or when Python prints the int. It's not actually part of the `int` or `bin` calls you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to CPython's source. Look for `long_format_binary`'s definition:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c